# Sending the signalr resolver to MapHubs() with Windsor Castle

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using SignalR version 1.1.2 with Castle Windsor and the line

```
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(signalrDependency);
```

is is not working anymore:

```
public static class RegisterHubs
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        var signalrDependencyContainer = new WindsorContainer().Install(new HubsInstaller());
        var signalrDependency = new SignalrDependencyResolver(signalrDependencyContainer.Kernel);
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = signalrDependency;
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(signalrDependency);
    }
}
```

It is saying

```
singalrdependencyresolver is not assignable to parameter type Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration.
```

Is it not needed anymore? I'm not sure about the behaviour if I just remove it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this would need to be a [`HubConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubconfiguration%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) instance, but if you've configured the default dependency resolver via `GlobalHost::DependencyResolver` (which you have in your sample) and don't require any further explicit configuration of the hubs, then there's no reason to pass anything into the `MapHubs` call.

Comment: Oh, ok, then maybe it's unrelated, but I'm getting the error "The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly." on RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); line. Do you know why?

Comment: I would open a separate question for that.